# What should I use to debug an application remotely when using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and newer versions

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I saw one question that is a little bit confusing and there are different answers on this question.

You plan to debug an application remotely by using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
You set a breakpoint in the code.
When you compile the application, you get the following error message: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." You need to ensure that you can debug the application remotely.
What should you do?

A. Modify the AssemblyInfo.cs file.
B. Copy .exe files to the Symbols folder on the local computer.
C. Copy .cs files to the remote server.
D. Use .NET Remote Symbol Loading.

Someone saying that A is the correct answer someone D,can someoebody tell me the right answer with explanation why it is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Symbols are in the PDB file.  Once application is started you can then add break points.   Before the program start you will always get the error you are seeing.

Comment: @jdweng so the right answer is ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you have to do is compile the application on the local machine and then copy it, including PDB symbols to the remote machine. There are also additional setup steps including making sure the debugging server is running on the remote machine, configuring the debugging server, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document." You need to ensure that you can debug the
>   application remotely. What should you do?

`No symbols` here indicates missing pdbs, or available pdbs' versions don't match.

If you get this error when remote-debugging in VS, we should firstly check whether the same bin folder has been copied to same path in remote server. Also, we need to make sure current `bin` folder is up-to-date in both local and remote machine.

**Description:** Every time after we make some little change to project, when we click the debug button in VS, it'll generates a new `bin/debug` folder with up-to-date contents. So for `remote-debugging`, we need to make sure we've build the project after the latest change to project's source files. And then copy the latest `bin/debug` folder to remote server. (Overwrite old one)

So I agree with **robbpriestley** and I don't think `A` and `D` above is the correct answer to resolve this kind of issue, especially when you use [VS Remote Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2019#download-and-install-the-remote-tools) for remote-debugging. Also, many factors can cause the error message above, so it shouldn't exist a `correct answer` among your A~D...

Hope it helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to let me know :)